# pyenv+venv 環境でpywin32によるサービス開始ができない

Tags: python, pyenv, python-venv

## 質問内容

後述する環境・設定・ソースにおいて、サービス登録後に開始・成功するにはどうすればよいでしょうか？

## 環境

Windows 10 Pro
Python 3.9.10 (pyenv+venv)
pip 23.0.1
pywin32 305

## 現象

venvでの仮想環境で、以下のサービス登録は成功します。管理ツールｰ>サービスを起動して、一覧にも登録されていることを確認しました。

```
> python app.py install
Installing service test_pywin32_service
copying host exe 'C:\...\ENV\lib\site-packages\win32\pythonservice.exe' -> 'C:\...\ENV\pythonservice.exe'
Service installed
```

サービスを実行しようとすると、失敗します。

```
> python app.py start
Starting service test_pywin32_service
Error starting service: そのサービスは指定時間内に開始要求または制御要求に応答しませんでした。
```

## やってみたこと

### システム環境変数のPathに追加

```
C:\...\ENV\Scripts\  ... python.exeがあります。
C:\...\ENV\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32
C:\...\ENV\Lib\site-packages\win32
```

以下のコマンドでPathに正しく登録されたことを確認しました。

```
echo %Path:;=&echo.%
```

この環境変数への適用により、pyenvよりも優先して、venv環境のPythonが実行されることを確認しました。
具体的には、以下のコマンドにより、インストールされているパッケージリストの違いにより判断しました。

```
python -m pip list
```

## pip インストールパッケージ

```
autopep8==2.0.2
  - pycodestyle [required: >=2.10.0, installed: 2.10.0]
  - tomli [required: Any, installed: 2.0.1]
flake8==6.0.0
  - mccabe [required: >=0.7.0,<0.8.0, installed: 0.7.0]
  - pycodestyle [required: >=2.10.0,<2.11.0, installed: 2.10.0]
  - pyflakes [required: >=3.0.0,<3.1.0, installed: 3.0.1]
pip-licenses==4.1.0
  - prettytable [required: >=2.3.0, installed: 3.6.0]
    - wcwidth [required: Any, installed: 0.2.6]
pip-review==1.3.0
  - packaging [required: Any, installed: 23.0]
  - pip [required: Any, installed: 23.0.1]
pipdeptree==2.5.2
pywin32==305
setuptools==58.1.0
wheel==0.38.4
```

## ソースコード

app.py

```py
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import logging
import os
import pathlib
import time

log_path = os.getenv("TEMP") + "\\test_pywin32_service\\test-service.log"
if not os.path.exists(log_path):
    ret_path = os.path.split(log_path)
    pathlib.Path(ret_path[0]).mkdir(
        parents=True,
        exist_ok=True
    )

logging.basicConfig(
    filename=log_path,
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format="%(asctime)s:LINE[%(lineno)s] %(levelname)s %(message)s"
)


class test_pywin32_service(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "test_pywin32_service"
    _svc_display_name_ = "TEST Service"
    _svc_description_ = '一定周期でログを出力する'
    _timeout_Milliseconds = 10000

    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        servicemanager.LogMsg(
            servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
            servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
            (self._svc_name_, '')
        )

        while True:
            ret = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(
                self.hWaitStop,
                self._timeout_Milliseconds
            )
            if ret == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                break

            time.sleep(5)

            logging.info(__class__.__name__)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.debug('start')
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(test_pywin32_service)
```

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるかも？ [How to Run Python Script as a Service (Windows & Linux)](https://oxylabs.io/blog/python-script-service-guide), [Running a Python Application as a Windows Service](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7318/python-as-a-windows-service/), [How to create windows service using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63754895/9014308), [Run Python script with parameter as Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66785319/9014308), [Run Python script as a windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69008155/9014308)

Comment: pyenvではなく、pyenv-winという派生(?)プロジェクトですよね？(ユーザー用の環境変数を使ってるようなので)実行ユーザーを合わせた上で環境変数のPATHなどの確認が必要なように見えます。pyenv-winは使ったことないですが、ソースを見たところbatとなぜかvbsを駆使してshim(s)を作成し、PATHで切り替える運用に見えました。

Answer (score 1):

ご紹介いただいた以下のサイトを参考にしたところ、サービス起動が成功しました。
[How to Run Python Script as a Service (Windows & Linux)](https://oxylabs.io/blog/python-script-service-guide)

最終的にPyInstallerでの提供を考えていたので、とても助かりました。

## ソースコード修正

```py
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import logging
import logging.handlers
import os
import pathlib
import sys
import time


def _logger_():
    log_path = os.getenv("TEMP") + "\\test_pywin32_service\\test-service.log"
    if not os.path.exists(log_path):
        ret_path = os.path.split(log_path)
        pathlib.Path(ret_path[0]).mkdir(
            parents=True,
            exist_ok=True
        )

    logging_format = '%(asctime)s %(threadName)s %(levelname)s:%(message)s'
    formatter = logging.Formatter(logging_format)

    root = logging.getLogger()

    handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(
        filename=log_path,
        mode="a",
        maxBytes=1*1024*1024,
        backupCount=2,
    )
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    root.addHandler(handler)
    root.setLevel('DEBUG')

    return root


class test_pywin32_service(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    # サービス名
    _svc_name_ = "test_pywin32_service"
    # 表示名(サービス画面にはこれを表示)
    _svc_display_name_ = "TEST Service"
    # サービスの説明
    _svc_description_ = '一定周期でログを出力する'
    # シグナルまでの待ち用タイムアウト時間(今回は10秒 = 10,000ミリ秒)
    _timeout_Milliseconds = 10000

    def __init__(self, args):
        self.logger = _logger_()
        self.logger.info('init')
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        self.logger.info('run')
        servicemanager.LogMsg(
            servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
            servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
            (self._svc_name_, '')
        )

        self.logger.info('start')

        while True:
            self.logger.info('alive')
            # イベントのシグナル化を10秒待つ
            ret = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(
                self.hWaitStop,
                self._timeout_Milliseconds
            )
            # サービス停止(イベントがシグナル化)ならば、処理を中止
            if ret == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                break

            time.sleep(1)

        self.logger.info('finish')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        servicemanager.Initialize()
        servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(test_pywin32_service)
        servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()
    else:
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(test_pywin32_service)
```

## サービス実行

PyInstallerでexe化

```
PyInstaller --hiddenimport win32timezone -F .\source\app.py
```

サービス登録

```
.\dist\app.exe install
```

サービスデバッグ起動

```
.\dist\app.exe debug
```

サービス開始

```
.\dist\app.exe start
```

サービス停止

```
.\dist\app.exe stop
```

サービス削除

```
.\dist\app.exe remove
```

## 新たな問題

debug起動では正常にログに出力できますが、start起動ではTempにフォルダ作成からできていないことが分かりました。この問題は、別の質問として投稿します。

Answer (score 0):

## 回答ではありません。

pywin32のサービスアプリの実体を調べたところ、以下に行き着きました。

https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/main/win32/src/PythonService.cpp

これをexeにビルドしたものがPythonService.exeがサービス・アプリの実体になり、サービス開始/停止時などに呼ばれます。
これをpyd(dll)にビルドしたものがservicemanager.pydになり、ユーザーpythonコードから呼ばれます。
サービス開始/停止時にこれが中継される以上、登録/削除管理もこちらからやるべきで、該当する処理が

win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine
https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/main/win32/Lib/win32serviceutil.py

になります。

```
C:\...\>python プログラム名.py install
```

などで登録でき、update/removeもあります。登録できたらあとはscコマンドなどを使えばサービスが実行できます。

```
C:\...\>sc start サービス名
```

実際に実行されるサービスはpythonservice.exeになります。登録された情報からユーザープログラムのクラスをロードして、所定のタイミングで呼んでくれますが、python自体はpythonservice.exeに埋め込まれたものを使用しており、実体としてはpythonXXX.dll(pywin32インストール時に決まる)の機能で動いています。なのでvenv用のsys.path設定が十分でなく、ユーザープログラムのロード中にimportなどでコケてしまいます(サービス開始に失敗したときはイベントログにちゃんとエラーが出ます)。

### PythonスクリプトでWindows Service

上記を元にvenv環境でpywin32を使用してWindowsのServiceを作ってみました。

#### venvで環境構築

```
C:\...\>python -m venv env
```

#### venv環境に入る/出る

```
C:\...\>.\env\Scripts\activate
(env)C:\...\>
作業
(env)C:\...\>deactivate
C:\...\>
```

#### pipでパッケージインストール

venv環境に入ってから

```
C:\...\>pip install -U pip setuptools
C:\...\>pip install pywin32
```

#### hoge.py

(カレントディレクトリに作成)

```py
import sys, os, logging, time
curdir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
logger = logging.getLogger('hogeservice')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
filehandler = logging.FileHandler(os.path.join(curdir, 'hogeservice.log'), encoding='utf8')
filehandler.setFormatter(formatter)
filehandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(filehandler)
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'env\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib'))
import servicemanager, win32serviceutil, win32service

class HogeService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = 'HogeService'
    _svc_display_name_ = 'ほげサービス'

    def __init__(self, args):
        logger.info('サービス初期化')
        self.stopRequested = False
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)

    def SvcStop(self):
        logger.info('サービス停止要求')
        self.stopRequested = True
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        logger.info('実行開始')
        while not self.stopRequested:
            logger.info('実行中！')
            time.sleep(1)
        logger.info('実行終了')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger.info(f'プログラム開始{sys.argv}')
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(HogeService)
    logger.info('プログラム終了')
```

#### サービス登録/実行/開始/削除

管理者でコマンドプロンプト実行

```
C:\...\>.\env\Scripts\activate
(env)C:\...\>python hoge.py install
Installing service HogeService
copying host exe 'C:\Users\user\python\asservice\tmp\env\lib\site-packages\win32\pythonservice.exe' -> 'C:\Users\user\python\asservice\tmp\env\pythonservice.exe'
Service installed

(env)C:\...\>sc query hogeservice

SERVICE_NAME: hogeservice
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        STATE              : 1  STOPPED
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 1077  (0x435)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0

(env)C:\...\>sc start hogeservice

SERVICE_NAME: hogeservice
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        STATE              : 2  START_PENDING
                                (NOT_STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x7d0
        PID                : 13920
        FLAGS              :

(env)C:\...\>sc query hogeservice

SERVICE_NAME: hogeservice
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0

(env)C:\...\>sc stop hogeservice

SERVICE_NAME: hogeservice
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        STATE              : 3  STOP_PENDING
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x1
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x1388

(env)C:\...\>sc query hogeservice

SERVICE_NAME: hogeservice
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        STATE              : 1  STOPPED
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0

(env)C:\...\>python hoge.py remove
Removing service HogeService
Service removed

(env)C:\...\>sc query hogeservice
[SC] EnumQueryServicesStatus:OpenService FAILED 1060:

指定されたサービスはインストールされたサービスとして存在しません。

(env)C:\...\>deactivate
C:\...\>
```

```
2023-03-15 23:18:07,714 - INFO - プログラム開始['hoge.py', 'install']
2023-03-15 23:18:07,752 - INFO - プログラム終了
2023-03-15 23:18:25,364 - INFO - サービス初期化
2023-03-15 23:18:25,365 - INFO - 実行開始
2023-03-15 23:18:25,365 - INFO - 実行中！
2023-03-15 23:18:26,366 - INFO - 実行中！
2023-03-15 23:18:27,366 - INFO - 実行中！
2023-03-15 23:18:28,367 - INFO - 実行中！
2023-03-15 23:18:29,367 - INFO - 実行中！
2023-03-15 23:18:30,368 - INFO - 実行中！
2023-03-15 23:18:31,368 - INFO - 実行中！
2023-03-15 23:18:32,048 - INFO - サービス停止要求
2023-03-15 23:18:32,369 - INFO - 実行終了
2023-03-15 23:19:03,637 - INFO - プログラム開始['hoge.py', 'remove']
2023-03-15 23:19:03,674 - INFO - プログラム終了
```

#### 質問に関する補足

原因はvenvに関連したsys.path設定(pythonモジュール検索パス設定)だと思います。
ただしpyenvは使っていません。バージョンを切り替えるだけで動かなくなる可能性があります。

#### 感想

pythonでWindowsサービスなんて、自分で軽く使いたいときくらいだと思うので、exe化なんて考えられません。実際どんどん書き換えられるので便利ですが。。。

誰かに頼まれてもお金をもらっても、もらった.exeは絶対実行しないように！

Comment: ありがとうございます。冷静に考えて、サービスプログラムにする必要性はあまりないなと感じました。そもそもPythonの有無、バージョン、環境変数の設定に頼っている時点でユーザー環境で事故があってしかるべきですね。